# segmentation fault (cored dumped)

Tags: c

I am receiving a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I execute the following code.

I am having difficulty determining why I am getting this error.  I'm thinking it's a pointer issue.

Here is the code

```
struct info{
char *host;
char *channel;
char *user;
}Ainfo;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *result2;
    int sock,getadd;

    Ainfo.host=argv[2];

    if(argc<3)
    {
       perror("too few Arguments\n");
       exit(0);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;


    getadd=getaddrinfo(Ainfo.host,PORT,(struct addrinfo *)&hints,&result);
    if(getadd!=0){
        perror("\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: . o O ( Why do people think, `#include`s aren't part of the program? )

Comment: Start by running it in your debugger to find out where the issue is.

Comment: Start by [learning how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Specifically learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash when it happens.

Comment: Note that when a program reports an error, it should usually not use `exit(0);` — it should use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or directly call `exit()` with some other number that is not a multiple of 256.

Comment: And think about the order you do things. For example, what happens with ` `Ainfo.host=argv[2]` if `argc < 3`?

Comment: @g-programmer To better help you a few more things items are needed.  First, if you can reduce the problem to a repeatable sample that others can see.  You are referencing only portions of your code so this use case is incomplete.  Can you provide the command line that is being used to start the program ?  As others have indicated, we don't know the number of structure of the command line arguments.  More information would allow others to help you.  Also, include what you have tried.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude though, nothing special would happen :P At most UB that "seems to work" if `argc < 2`...

Comment: What is `PORT` defined as?  POSIX says [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html)
has the prototype `int getaddrinfo(const char *restrict nodename, const char *restrict servname, const struct addrinfo *restrict hints, struct addrinfo **restrict res);` and also stipulates:  _The_ nodename _and_ servname _arguments are either null pointers or pointers to null-terminated strings. One or both of these two arguments shall be supplied by the application as a non-null pointer._

Comment: @Hogstrom name irc.freenode.net #cnit_bot_test it's the command line being used in this program

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler the PORT is set to 6667 `#define PORT 6667`

Comment: If you have `#define PORT 6667`, then that does not look like either a NULL pointer or a null-terminated string.  So it isn't a big surprise (to me) that your code is crashing.  It _is_ a surprise that you are not getting compiler warnings telling you that you're doing it wrong.  Get the warnings enabled, or get a better compiler.  And heed the warnings — the compiler knows more about C than you do.  I rarely run code that doesn't compile cleanly with `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes …` (and the `-Werror` makes sure I deal with the warnings!).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler you are right, i define PORT as number and it should be char type, my fault and i admit it....the problem is solved yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring key comments into an answer.*</sup>

What is `PORT` defined as? POSIX says [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) has the prototype

> ```
> int getaddrinfo(const char *restrict nodename, const char *restrict servname,
>                 const struct addrinfo *restrict hints, struct addrinfo **restrict res);
> ```

and also stipulates:

> The `nodename` and `servname` arguments are either null pointers or pointers to null-terminated strings. One or both of these two arguments shall be supplied by the application as a non-null pointer.

The OP notes:

- The PORT is set to 6667 — `#define PORT 6667`

If you have `#define PORT 6667`, then that does not look like either a null pointer or a null-terminated string. So it isn't a big surprise (to me) that your code is crashing.

It is a surprise that you are not getting compiler warnings telling you that you're doing it wrong. Get the warnings enabled, or get a better compiler. And heed the warnings — the compiler knows more about C than you do. I rarely run code that doesn't compile cleanly with

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes …
```

(The `-Werror` makes sure I deal with the warnings because the compilation fails if there are any!  I sometimes add some more warnings; I rarely remove any of them.)